# Python 3.x WSGI Testing framework

Tags: python, testing, python-3.x, integration-testing, wsgi

Given that webtest doesn't seem to have a 3.x version (or any plans to develop one), are there any solutions for automated system testing of a WSGI application? I know unittest for unit testing - I'm more interested in the moment in whole systems tests.

I'm not looking for tools to help *develop* an application - just *test* it.

Comment: just so you know what the situation is. webtest depends on webob. there is work being done right now on webob to make it work on python 3. It's not too much of a stretch to imagine that when the work on webob is done, webtest should just work on python 3 or should with minimal effort. So it's not exactly correct to say "or any plans to develop one" but now you know the situation.

Comment: That's good to hear. Might be good information for the WebTest wiki. The only post I found even partially related was [this post](http://groups.google.com/group/paste-users/browse_thread/thread/af25d39867d4cbe1), in which someone else mentioned Python 3 support but never received a response.

Comment: This questions is a few years old now and things might have changed meanwhile. Without pointing out any changelog or something, I can just tell that I am using `webtest` successfully with a Python 3.4 application (based on the `Falcon` framework).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case anyone else comes upon this, I ended up writing a solution myself. 
Here's a very simple class I use - I just inherit from `WSGIBaseTest` instead of `TestCase`, and get a method `self.request()` that I can pass requests into. 
It stores `cookies`, and will automatically send them into the application on later requests (until `self.new_session()` is called).

```
import unittest
from wsgiref import util
import io

class WSGIBaseTest(unittest.TestCase):
    '''Base class for unit-tests. Provides up a simple interface to make requests
    as though they came through a wsgi interface from a user.'''
    def setUp(self):
        '''Set up a fresh testing environment before each test.'''
        self.cookies = []
    def request(self, application, url, post_data = None):
        '''Hand a request to the application as if sent by a client.
        @param application: The callable wsgi application to test.
        @param url: The URL to make the request against.
        @param post_data: A string.'''
        self.response_started = False
        temp = io.StringIO(post)
        environ = {
            'PATH_INFO': url,
            'REQUEST_METHOD': 'POST' if post_data else 'GET',
            'CONTENT_LENGTH': len(post),
            'wsgi.input': temp,
            }
        util.setup_testing_defaults(environ)
        if self.cookies:
            environ['HTTP_COOKIE'] = ';'.join(self.cookies)
        self.response = ''
        for ret in application(environ, self._start_response):
            assert self.response_started
            self.response += str(ret)
        temp.close()
        return response
    def _start_response(self, status, headers):
        '''A callback passed into the application, to simulate a wsgi
        environment.

        @param status: The response status of the application ("200", "404", etc)
        @param headers: Any headers to begin the response with.
        '''
        assert not self.response_started
        self.response_started = True
        self.status = status
        self.headers = headers
        for header in headers:
            # Parse out any cookies and save them to send with later requests.
            if header[0] == 'Set-Cookie':
                var = header[1].split(';', 1)
                if len(var) > 1 and var[1][0:9] == ' Max-Age=':
                    if int(var[1][9:]) > 0:
                        # An approximation, since our cookies never expire unless
                        # explicitly deleted (by setting Max-Age=0).
                        self.cookies.append(var[0])
                    else:
                        index = self.cookies.index(var[0])
                        self.cookies.pop(index)
    def new_session(self):
        '''Start a new session (or pretend to be a different user) by deleting
        all current cookies.'''
        self.cookies = []
```